# In SQL, when using an aggregate function with the 'having' clause, does that function has to be in the select statement?

Tags: sql, database

Does the 'aggregate_function(column_name)' in the select statement have to be the same in the `having` clause?

```
SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name
HAVING aggregate_function(column_name) operator value;
```

Comment: You can't possibly be using SQL Server (a Microsoft product) and MySQL (an Oracle product) simultaneously. Pick the tag that is actually applicable to your question. The two products have vastly different syntax and functionality. Tags have specific meaning here. Please don't just randomly add them because they have words you're familiar with or they seem similar.

Comment: No, it does not in general have to be in the `select`.

Comment: It does not have to be the same as what's in the `HAVING` clause. You just have to have an aggregate of some kind when selecting fields that you have not grouped. by.
Why did you not just try it? 

Comment: @KenWhite: why? I used to work on a system where the customer can choose between SQL Server, Oracle and MS Access as the DBMS. This is one of the reasons why I tend to prefer Standard SQL!

Comment: @onedaywhen, this is not just about backward compatibility.   **having** is a syntactic sugar. You can live without  it but would you really want to start nesting queries every time you want to filter on aggregation results? Teradata have inserted there own **QUALIFY** clause for filtering on windows functions and the code is so much cleaner there. No more `select ... from (select ...,row_number() over (partition by ... order by ...) as rn ... from ...) t where rn = 1;`

Comment: @onedaywhen Yes... If we could only find a short syntax that will stand for this verbose derived table syntax, something like a single word that means "wrap the query with another query and than use the aggregate result from the inner query to filter the records"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, you are actually right... I could have swear that the question was different, but on the other hand I didn't sleep much in the last 24 hours. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Can you imagine using SQL without derived tables? Me either. `HAVING` was invented very early on, before it was realized that without derived tables SQL wasn't relationally complete. Now that problem has been solved (and many decades ago too) we no longer need to bother to learn `HAVING`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can use different aggregate function in HAVING Clause . It is not depending on the SELECT Clause

Example:

```
SELECT column_name, SUM(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY column_name
HAVING COUNT(column_name) > 1;
```

This is also valid:

```
SELECT column_name_1, SUM(column_name_2)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name_3 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY column_name_1
HAVING COUNT(column_name_4) > 1;
```